# No code coverage on attachment test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I could use some help with the code coverage on my class.  The test class is not complete.  I was trying to just get coverage on the program object and then work from there but I am not getting any coverage at all.
My questions are:

- How do I cover the `List<Id>`
- Why am I not enter the first Attachment for loop
- How do I cover variable assignment like `parentObjectType == 'Program__c'`.

Code:

```
Map<Id, List<ContentDocumentLink>> linkMap = new Map<Id, List<ContentDocumentLink>>();
Map<String, Directory__c> directoryMap = new Map<String, Directory__c>();
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl_List = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
public ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
List<Attachment__c> categoryvals = new List<Attachment__c>();
public String parentId;
public String catvalue;
public String folderparentId;
public string parentObjectType;
public Map<Id,Program__c> ProgramMap = new Map<Id,Program__c>();
public Map<Id,Permit__c>  PermitMap  = new Map<Id,Permit__c>();

global override void bulkBeforeExtended() {
    if( Trigger.isUpdate ){
        List<Id> docIds = new List<Id>();
        List<String> parentIds = new List<String>();
        List<Id> progRecordIds = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> perRecordIds = new List<Id>();
               
        for( Attachment__c attrecord : ( List<Attachment__c> ) Trigger.new ){
            Id recId = Id.valueOf(attrecord.Parent_ID__c ); 
            parentObjectType = String.valueOf( recId.getSObjectType());

            if(parentObjectType == 'Program__c' ){
                progRecordIds.add(attrecord.Parent_ID__c);
            }
            if(parentObjectType == 'Permit__c' ){
                perRecordIds.add(attrecord.Parent_ID__c);
            }
        }
        if (!progRecordIds.isEmpty()) {
            programMap.putall([Select Project__c from Program__c WHERE Id =: ProgRecordIds]);  
        }
        if (!perRecordIds.isEmpty()) {
            permitMap.putall([Select Project__c from Permit__c WHERE Id =: perRecordIds]); 
        }
        if (!jobRecordIds.isEmpty()) {
            jobMap.putall([Select Project__c from Job__c WHERE Id =: JobRecordIds]);
        }
      
        for( Attachment__c record : ( List<Attachment__c> ) Trigger.new ){
            Id docId = record.ContentDocumentId__c;
                parentId = record.Parent_ID__c ;
                Id recId = Id.valueOf(record.Parent_ID__c ); 
                parentObjectType = String.valueOf( recId.getSObjectType() );
   
                if( ProgramMap.containsKey(record.Parent_ID__c)){ 
                    for(Program__c prog :ProgramMap.values()){
                        parentId = prog.Project__c;
                    }
                }
                if( PermitMap.containsKey(record.Parent_ID__c)){ 
                    parentId = record.Proj__c;
                    record.sobject__c ='Project';
                }
                }
             
                if( docId != null ){    
                    docIds.add( docId );
                }
              
                if( parentId != null ){    
                    parentIds.add( parentId );
                } 
              
                if( record.sobject__c != null ){    
                    categoryvals.add( record );
                }       
        }

        list<Directory__c> dirs = [
            SELECT id,Directory_Template__c,Name,ParentId__c,Sobject__c,
                (Select Id,Name, Directory__c, Folder_Template__c,Parent_File_Folder__c FROM File_Folders__r ORDER BY Name)
            FROM Directory__c 
            WHERE ParentId__c IN: parentIds
        ];
       
        if( !dirs.isEmpty() ){
            for( Directory__c dir : dirs ){
                this.directoryMap.put( dir.ParentId__c, dir );
            }
        }

        List<ContentDocumentLink> linkList = [ SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: docIds ];
        if( !linkList.isEmpty() ){
            for( ContentDocumentLink link : linkList ){
                List<ContentDocumentLink> links = this.linkMap.containsKey( link.ContentDocumentId )
                    ? this.linkMap.get( link.ContentDocumentId ) : new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
                links.add( link );
                this.linkMap.put( link.ContentDocumentId, links );
            }
        }
    }
}
global override void bulkAfterExtended() {
}

global override void beforeInsertExtended(SObject so) {
    Attachment__c newAttachment = ( Attachment__c ) so;
    this.getObjectType(newAttachment);
}
global override void beforeUpdateExtended(SObject oldso, SObject newso) {
    Attachment__c newAttachment = ( Attachment__c ) newSo;
    folderparentId = newAttachment.Parent_Id__c;
    Id recId = Id.valueOf(newAttachment.Parent_ID__c );
    parentObjectType = String.valueOf( recId.getSObjectType() );
    this.getParentObjectType(parentObjectType,newAttachment);      

    if( directoryMap.containsKey( folderparentId)){           
        Directory__c dir = this.directoryMap.get( folderparentId );
        List<File_Folder__c> folders = dir.File_Folders__r;
        system.debug('dir.File_Folders__r '+ dir.File_Folders__r);
        List<ContentDocumentLink> links = this.linkMap.get( newAttachment.ContentDocumentId__c );

        for (ContentDocumentLink cont : links ){
            for (File_Folder__c folder: folders ){
                if(newattachment.Document_Type__c == folder.name ){
                    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    cdl.LinkedEntityId = folder.Id;
                    cdl.ContentDocumentId = cont.ContentDocumentId;
                    cdl.ShareType = 'V';
                    cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    newAttachment.File_Folder__c = folder.Id;
                    cdl_List.add(cdl);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
global override void afterUpdateExtended(SObject oldso, SObject newso) {}
global override void afterInsertExtended(SObject newso) {} 
global override void andFinallyExtended() {

  if (!Trigger.isDelete) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            try {
                if (cdl_List.size() > 0) {
                    insert cdl_List;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    if (!Trigger.isDelete) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            try {
                if (categoryvals.size() > 0) {
                    update categoryvals;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}

private void getParentObjectType(String tempParentObjectType,Attachment__c newAttachment){

    if( tempParentObjectType == 'Program__c'  ){
        folderparentId = parentId;
        newAttachment.sobject__c='Program';
    }
    else{
        folderparentId = parentId;
        newAttachment.sobject__c='Project';
    }
}

private void getObjectType(Attachment__c newAttachment){
    if( this.linkMap.containsKey( newAttachment.ContentDocumentId__c ) ){
        List<ContentDocumentLink> links = this.linkMap.get( newAttachment.ContentDocumentId__c );
        if( !links.isEmpty() ){
            for( ContentDocumentLink link : links ){
                String objectType = String.valueOf( link.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() );
                Directory__c dir = this.directoryMap.containsKey( link.LinkedEntityId )
                    ? this.directoryMap.get( link.LinkedEntityId ) : null;
                if( dir != null ){
                    switch on ( objectType ){
                        when 'Program__c' {
                            newAttachment.Program__c = link.LinkedEntityId;
                        }
     
                        when 'Permit__c' {
                           newAttachment.Permit__c = link.LinkedEntityId;
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@IsTest
private class AttachmentTriggerHandlerTest {
@TestSetup
static void setupTestData() {
    Directory_Template__c dirTemplate = new Directory_Template__c(
        Name = 'Directory Template Test',
        Sobject__c = 'Project',
        Active__c = true
    );
    insert dirTemplate;
}

@isTest
private static void TestTriggerFunctions(){

    List<Directory_Template__c> dirTemplates = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Directory_Template__c
    ];
    
    System.assertEquals( 1, dirTemplates.size(), '1 template found' );

    Program__c prog = new Program__c(
            Name = 'Test Program',
            Operator__c = 'MBNL',
            Directory_Template__c = dirTemplates[ 0 ].Id
    );
    insert prog;

    Attachment__c attach = new Attachment__c();       
    attach.Name='Test Attachment';
    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Test Attachment Body');
    attach.body=bodyBlob;
    attach.parentId=prog.id;
    insert attach;
    
    List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:prog.id];
    System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());

    Blob contentData = Blob.valueOf( 'Test File' );
    String documentName = 'testfile.txt';

    ContentVersion newDocument = new ContentVersion(
        Title = documentName,
        VersionData = contentData,
        PathOnClient = documentName
    );

    insert newDocument;

    List<ContentVersion> versionVerify = [
        SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId
        FROM ContentVersion
        WHERE Id =: newDocument.Id
    ];
    System.assertEquals( 1, versionVerify.size() );

    List<ContentDocument> documents = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM ContentDocument
        WHERE Id =: versionVerify[ 0 ].ContentDocumentId
    ];

    System.assertEquals( 1, documents.size() );

    ContentDocumentLink newLink = new ContentDocumentLink(
        LinkedEntityId = projects[ 0 ].Id,
        ContentDocumentId = documents[ 0 ].Id,
        ShareType = 'V',
        Visibility = 'AllUsers'
    );
    insert newLink;
}
```

}

Comment: David, thank you for the reply.  Unfortunately I am still not seeing what I am missing.  I have created an attachment record in my test class and added an update to to the attachment but I am still not even entering the first attachment loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate causes I can see and there may be others:

1. Your trigger (handler) is coded to respond to changes for a custom object called `Attachment__c` but your test is manipulating the standard Salesforce object `Attachment`.
2. Your test only does `insert` DMLs but your trigger (handler) starts with a guard that means it only responds to `update` DMLs.

Comment: Updated the attachment object reference.  Tried adding an update to the attachment but receiving error: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.  I thought the code at the bottom of my test class would have covered this